# Make motor run slower

Tags: motor

I was wondering if anyone could help me or give advice. I have an old electric green goods shredder. I want to use the motor to make a wood turning machine. How do I add a simple speed control to the motor?

FYI, I'm a complete novice. I have no experience in electrical circuits but I know the obvious stuff like +/-

Any help would be great.

Comment: As a complete novice with no experience in electrical circuits you should not do it.

Comment: Hello ... start with identifying the motor.  Any labels on it which describe exactly what kind of motor it is?

Comment: use gear reduction

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Unfortunately, this site is about electronics design and, considering your honest skill self-assessment, your problem is best solved with a pre-made motor speed control board or module. The site doesn't do part recommendations so you're not on the right site, I'm afraid. But you'll find plenty on the interweb if you search for 'motor speed board' or 'motor speed controller'. You'll need the operating voltage and max. (stall) current of your motor. Good luck with it and, again, welcome.

Comment: Examine the motor - does it have a commutator and brushes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_(electric)

Comment: use a power drill instead, quite a lot of torque is needed for wood turning, so something with gear reduction will help.

Answer (score 1):

There's various type of AC motor. I assume you are talking about single-phase AC motor. But I'm suggesting not to do anything with it without the help of an experienced person.

The speed of any AC motor can be changed. The most popular way is the variable frequency driver. Besides you can use Triac. Nowadays, solid-state relay IC has become very popular instead of Triac.

And if you start to work with it, be aware of the heat generated in various IC.

Watch these youtube videos: [VFD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7jFGOn6xfU) , [Triac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bp-lJ-zLQLM) ,[Solid-state relay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbQiRM9p0j0)

And you will find all of these in any electrical hardware store. 
[Solid-state relay](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32880595456.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.15841bddCmsW8p&algo_pvid=8bc179f3-37ce-4e59-9827-d2c9da530a0c&algo_expid=8bc179f3-37ce-4e59-9827-d2c9da530a0c-0&btsid=0ab6f83115852530643323787e0fcd&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)
[Triac dimmer](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32957722934.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.35eed964nHOnEL&algo_pvid=1503aa6e-660d-4cab-8d40-5b0d6407ce52&algo_expid=1503aa6e-660d-4cab-8d40-5b0d6407ce52-0&btsid=0ab6f82315852531244362146e3ac8&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)
[VFD](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32968559810.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.735c78c6shuxog&algo_pvid=eae2f8c6-bab0-4508-ba63-d6f32ae4bb9b&algo_expid=eae2f8c6-bab0-4508-ba63-d6f32ae4bb9b-0&btsid=0ab50f6115852532215124839e6515&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

I'm saying again, don't do these alone. Playing with high voltage has two outputs: 1. Coooool, 2. You are in hospital or dead

Answer (score 0):

Not all electric motors can be made to run slower. So without knowing what you have, nobody can help you. But as a general rule if this motor came from a household type machine made to run on single phase AC power, it most likely cannot be made to run slower. So your only options to change the speed would involve mechanical means (belts, pulleys, gears etc.), something not covered by this site.

Comment: Variable frequency drive?

Comment: Who said single-phase AC motor can't be made mode slower? I've done it many many times.

Comment: Haven't you seen a table fan or ceiling fan?

Comment: An AC induction motor typically used on something like a "shredder" is typically a Capacitor Start motor. If you attempt to use a VFD, triac control or anything else that lowers the torque and/or speed, the centrifugal switch re-closes, the starting capacitors are placed back into the circuit and if they don't fry the electronics in the speed controller, the capacitors themselves over heat and short. It's a race to failure. You can vary the voltage on small Shaded Pole motors used on fans to make them lose torque and slow down, but those would be useless on a shredder.

Comment: my shredder has a universal motor,  I can't see a single phase induction motor being practical on a portable shredder.